# Memory Error while Using PIL, NUMpy,pywt for satellite images

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, satellite-image, pywt

I am getting a memory error.

How to resolve my problem?

It seems that satellite images take more memory. Which platform should I use for satellite images?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pywt

im = Image.open("......\B2.TIF") #multispectral image
im2 = Image.open(".......\B8.TIF") #panchromatic image

arr1 = np.array(im)
arr2 = np.array(im1)
coeffs = pywt(arr1, 'haar')

MemoryError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8f5b42e85336> in <module>()
----> 1 coeffs1 = pywt.dwt2(arr2, 'haar')

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywt\_multidim.pyc in         dwt2(data,wavelet,mode, axes)
 66                          "axes")
 67
 68     coefs = dwtn(data, wavelet, mode, axes)
 69     return coefs['aa'], (coefs['da'], coefs['ad'], coefs['dd'])
 70

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywt\_multidim.pyc in dwtn(data, wavelet, mode, axes)
179         new_coeffs = []
180         for subband, x in coeffs:
181             cA, cD = dwt_axis(x, wavelet, mode, axis)
182             new_coeffs.extend([(subband + 'a', cA),
183                                (subband + 'd', cD)])

pywt\_extensions\_dwt.pyx in pywt._extensions._dwt.dwt_axis    (pywt\_extensions\_dwt.c:5503)()
pywt\_extensions\_dwt.pyx in pywt._extensions._dwt.dwt_axis (pywt\_extensions    \_dwt.c:4651)()

MemoryError:
coeffs2 = pywt(arr2, 'haar')'
```

Comment: always add full error message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:satpy]?  It uses dask which may help you with memory.